# Date field with selection back more than 20 years

Tags: 7

I have a date field:

[image: field]

the year selection is possible **20** years back from now:

[image: option]

But I need it to be **25** years. Is this a fix Drupal setting or can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is actually -10 years

[image]

Since yours is longer, scroll own and select "Other" and type -25

[image]

Save settings

Now when you edit again, you should see

[image]